# How would you know which element of an ItemsControl sends an event in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say I currently have an ItemsControl whose DataTemplate is a bunch of buttons.  I'm wiring up these buttons' click events, but how am I to know which button was clicked?  Should I not use a ItemsControl?

I'm trying to have no code-behind, but being pragmatic may be necessary.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="10">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ItemsControlButtonClicked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know what `Item` was clicked, then pass `{Binding }` as the `CommandParameter` and it will pass the selected object to your Command

If you want to know what `Button` was clicked, I would do that in the code-behind since ViewModels do not need to know anything about the UI, and that includes buttons.

Also since your control is a Button, you should use the `Command` property instead of a Click trigger.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ItemsControlButtonClicked}" />
```

Comment: And you can set the Command\CommandParameter attributes directly on the `Button` (without the `EventTrigger`) to achieve the same effect

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, but for some reason the command isn't being called.  Is the fact that the command is in a datatemplate change the datacontext?  Intellisense is also cannot resolve the symbol for the command.

Comment: The command it is trying to execute is  `ItemsControl.Items[X].ItemsControlButtonClicked`, which should be of type `ICommand`. If your command doesn't exist here, you need to change your binding. I haven't worked with MVVMLight's Interaction Triggers, so I can't tell you why you're getting an intellisense error, but you might want to check out their documentation for that.

Comment: Also, since you're using a Button control, why not just use the `Command` property instead of the click event? See the edit to my answer.

Comment: No reason; Wasn't thinking the event I wanted (click) was the default for Command.  The problem is the event I want to raise is in the UserControl's DataContext.  I tried to make a binding to call it there but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I completely understand the problem now.  The problem is I don't know how to send the command to the root usercontrol's DataContext.

Comment: You're currently binding to the Button's `DataContext`, not your UserControl's `DataContext`, and your Button's DataContext is equal to `ItemsControl.Item[X]`, not `UserControl.DataContext`. You'll need something like `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ItemsControlButtonClicked}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters along with the command and based on these parameters you can find out which button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

In my project I also use the MVVM Light I has an dropdown with collection of items, and a button which user press and action depend on selected item from drop down 
you should create a Relay command with parameter look at the example from my code

```
  public RelayCommand<Project> StartTimer { get; private set; }//declare command

   StartTimer = new RelayCommand<Project>(OnStartTimer);

    private void OnStartTimer(Project project)
    {

        if (project != null)
        {

            currentProject = project;

            if (!timer.IsTimerStopped)
            {
                timer.StopTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                Caption = "Stop";
                timer.StartTimer();
            }
        }
```

on the view I bind the drop down with collection of  class Project
and for button command parameter I bind the selected item form drop down
 look at the code

```
   <ComboBox Name="projectcomboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}"    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
              SelectedValuePath="Name"  SelectedIndex="0"  >
    </ComboBox>
      <Button Name="timerButton" Content="{Binding Path=Caption}" Command="{Binding Path=StartTimer}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=projectcomboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"  ></Button>
```

pay attention to Command and CommandParameter binding

also you can use this approache not only for drop down

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the Sender.DataContext which is the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Create command properties in your view model class (using Josh Smith's `RelayCommand` pattern is the simplest way to do this) and bind each button's `Command` to the appropriate one.  Not only is this straightforward to do and simple to maintain, it also gives you an easy way of implementing the enable/disable behavior when you need to.